# Mathematical framework for explaining why the equations of motion look different in non-inertial frames

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames

How do the equations of motion look different in non-inertial frames? Is there a mathematical framework that we could use to explain this fact?

Comment: Is this in reference to the theory of special relativity? If it is, the theory explicitly says that both reference frames follow the same laws of physics.

Comment: Have you studied special relativity? What motivates this question?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different mathematical frameworks that you can use to work with physical quantities independently of the coordinates.

One is tensors from pseudo-Riemannian geometry. Tensors are designed so that under any arbitrary change of coordinates the components of the tensors will change in exactly the right way to correct for the change in the coordinates. In other words, a given tensor in one coordinates is the same object as in another set of coordinates, just expressed appropriately in each.

The other major approach is differential forms.  Differential forms are particularly suited to doing integration over curves, surfaces, and volumes independently of the coordinates that you use to describe those integrations.

Physical theories can often be very succinctly written in both of these forms. For example Maxwell’s microscopic equations can be written as a differential forms equation as: $$d\mathbf F=0$$ $$d\star \mathbf F=\mathbf J$$ This compact notation includes all of the same meaning as the usual expression of Maxwell’s equations.